# Put HTML or images in the xAxis

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts

Is there a way to display images in the xAxis of a simple bar chart?

This is what I've tried so far:

I'm trying to overwrite what is displayed in the **tickLabelComponent** from the **VictoryAxis** using a custom component.

```
       <VictoryAxis
            // tickValues specifies both the number of ticks and where
            // they are placed on the axis
            tickValues={props.xTickValues}
            tickFormat={props.xTickFormat}
            // ChartBarCustomLabel is the name of my custom component
            tickLabelComponent={<ChartBarCustomLabel xAxisInformation={props.xAxisInformation} />}
        />
```

The custom component receives an array of images in the prop **xAxisInformation**.

Here it is:

```
const ChartBarCustomLabel = (props) => {

return (
    <div>
        <img src={props.xAxisInformation[props.index].icon} alt="" key={props.xAxisInformation[props.index].id}/>
    </div>
);
```

};

In the custom component, I try to get the icon using the **index** which is a prop provided for the **tickLabelComponent**. But nothing is displayed.

In fact, if I inspect the code using React Developer Tools, the image is there...

[image]

...but nothing is rendered.

[image]

I supposed html or images cannot be displayed in the **tickLabelComponent** and that I should use another Victory component instead. But Which one is the correct?

Or maybe there is another way to accomplish this.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Victory renders its data components and label components inside a svg tag. So if I want to use non-svg elements I need to wrap them in `<foreignObject>`

The only disadvantage is that foreignObject is not supported in some browsers and that I need to provide the position.

Anyways, the custom component is now like this:

```
const ChartBarCustomLabel = (props) => {
    return (
        <foreignObject style={{ paddingTop: String(props.xAxisImagesTopPadding) + "px", paddingLeft: String(props.xAxisImagesLeftInitialPadding + (props.xAxisImagesTickSize * props.index)) + "px" }}>
            {
                props.xAxisInformation[props.index] !== undefined ?
                    <img style={{ minHeight: String(props.xAxisImagesMinHeight) + "px", minWidth: String(props.xAxisImagesMinWidth) + "px" }} src={props.xAxisInformation[props.index].icon} alt="" key={props.xAxisInformation[props.index].id} />
                    : null
            }
        </foreignObject>
    );
};
```

And works just fine!